# Using JAXB annotations with RestEasy

Tags: java, web-services, annotations, jaxb, resteasy

I'm trying to use JAXB annotations with RestEasy in order to choose names and elements order in my JSON output.

Somehow, it isn't working, even if the RestEasy doc says it's possible.

Here some code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "translation")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "translation", propOrder = {
    "key",
    "value"
})
public class TranslationDTO {

  public TranslationDTO() {}
  public TranslationDTO(Translation translation) {
    setKey(translation.getTranslationKey().getValue());
    setValue(translation.getContent());
    //setCreationDate(translation.getCreatedTimestamp());
  }

  @XmlElement(name = "key")
    private String key;

  @XmlElement(name = "value")
    private String value;

    //private Date creationDate;

    @XmlElement(name = "key")
    public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }

    public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

    public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

    /*@XmlElement(name = "creationDate")
    public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
  }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
  }*/

}
```

And here an example output:

```
{
    "name":"i18nhelp",
    "currentVersion":"1",
    "currentTotalKeys":28,
    "oldTotalKeys":0,
    "totalLanguages":2,
    "languageDtos":[{
        "name":"Anglais",
        "iso639":"en",
        "totalCurTrans":28,
        "newCurTrans":28,
        "oldTrans":0
    },
    {
        "name":"Français",
        "iso639":"fr",
        "totalCurTrans":28,
        "newCurTrans":28,
        "oldTrans":0
    }]
}
```

The JAXB annotations don't seem to be taken in account at all.

Any idea will be considered...

Comment: isn't it XmlAccessType.PROPERTY to automatically bind getters and XmlAccessType.FIELD for fields? did you try removing the redundant annotations? or instead going with XmlAccessType.NONE?

Comment: The following may help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Nice and helpful blog, by the way, Blaise. Actually, the JAXB annotations don't seem to be taken in account at all. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @guido: after reading Blaise's blog, I think I should use XmlAccessType.NONE and remove the annotations to my getters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using JBoss (or WildFly as it's now called) as an application server, you may be experiencing RestEasy using the Jackson (http://jackson.codehaus.org/) JSON marshaller, which has its own annotations – you can find the documentation linked from Jackson's homepage. They are a bit more expressive than "just" JAXB, you may want to consider them if you specifically target JSON output only.

If you would rather only use JAXB, as you example indicates, you can switch from Jackson to something different by specifying which resteasy provider module you want to use in a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13533317/2740117).

Comment: I'm not able to check if your answer solves the problem I had at that time, as I'm not working for the same company. But your point is interesting, though. I didn't know Jackson had its own annotations. Does it mean it's not compliant with JAXB?

Comment: To much of my own frustration, sadly, Jackson does not appear to be compatible with JAXB. At least as of the version included with the JBoss I work on (7.1.1), which is Jackson 1.9.2. IMO, Jackson produces much saner JSON, which is why for my situation, I chose to stick with it and annotate everything with JAXB as well as Jackson annotations.