# Configure Wildfly 8.1 to use Jettison

Tags: json, jaxb, jackson, wildfly, jettison

I have an interesting problem in that my Wildfly 8.1 installation is using Jackson (not Jackson 2) for marshalling classes to JSON. I would like to use Jettison in order to take advantage of the JAXB annotations I have in my classes.

To force the server to use Jettison instead of Jackson, I've performed the following steps :

1. Modified the POM.xml dependencies to depend on the **resteasy-jettison-provider** module with the scope set as **provided**

   < dependency >
       < groupId >org.jboss.resteasy</ groupId >
       < artifactId >resteasy-jettison-provider</ artifactId >
       < version >3.0.8.Final</ version >
       < scope >provided</ scope >
   </ dependency >
2. Modified the **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** in my WEB-INF directory to include the jettison module and exclude all jackson modules:

   < jboss-deployment-structure >
       < deployment >
         < exclusions >
           < module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
           < module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
           < module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
           < module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
           < module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
           < module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
         </ exclusions >
         < dependencies >
           < module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider" />
         </ dependencies >
       </ deployment >
     </ jboss-deployment-structure >

When I start the server, I send a simple bit of JSON to log into my application:

```
{ 
    "authRequest":   
    { 
      "appLogin":"restful",
      "appPassword":"mypassword" 
    }
}
```

However, I get the following exception from the server when I send this code snippet:

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "authRequest" (class com.myapp.AppAuthRequest), not marked as ignorable
```

From that exception, it looks like Jackson is still being used, despite my configuration.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong or what misconfiguration I have?

Comment: This was answered by [this previous question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831119/set-json-provider-at-resteasy-on-jboss-7-1-1)